# Password protect folder on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, password-protection

Well, this already has been asked, but I want something a little bit different. What I want is a way to protect a folder or a file with a password, but I don't want to hide it, just protect it, so, when I try to open the folder/file it ask me for the password, and when I introduce the password it give me access to that folder/file. I tried a lot of programs but I can't find what I really want. Can someone help me?

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Comment: Try 7Zip, just create an archive, put your file in it and add a password to the archive

Comment: No, I don't compress the files or folders, I just want to protect with password. But thank's.

Comment: You don't have to compress them...

Comment: I don't  want to create and archive... I just want my normal folder protected with password.

Comment: This feature is not supported natively in Windows.

Comment: I know... I'm asking for some third party tool.

Comment: I'm not sure if this meets your requirements, but given you're running Windows 7 Ultimate, you can use [Encrypting File System](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-is-Encrypting-File-System-EFS) to prevent any account other than yours (even other administrators) on your computer from accessing your files.  This functionality is also available in Windows 7 Professional and Enterprise, but Windows 7 Starter, Home Basic, and Home Premium only support decryption and modification of files already encrypted and cannot encrypt new or existing files using EFS.

Comment: If you're asking for a third-party tool, then your question is off topic for being a software recommendation request. Also, 7zip counts as a third party tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try http://www.iobit.com/password-protected-folder.html

Described as
*Protected Folder is designed to password-protect, guard and lock your folders & files from being seen, read or modified in Windows 7, Vista, XP and Server 2008, 2003. It works like a safety box, just drag and drop the folders or files you want to lock or protect into Protected Folder, then no one can see, read or modify them. Whether you are concerned with privacy, data theft, data loss, or data leaks, Protected Folder is an ideal tool for you.*

And the bit which should interest you is: *Easily block access to files, folders, and programs you choose. You can password protect or lock folder and its files then others can see it but cannot access, read or view its content.*

Comment: I don't want to hide the folders... Just password protect those folders.

Comment: eh? Did you read the last paragraph of my answer? *then others can see it but cannot access*

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. It's almost what I want, but thank you.